# How to pass classpath via rest api in apache flink 1.9

Tags: apache-flink

We successfully star jobs via cli, something like:

```
./bin/flink run -p 1 -C file://tmp/test-fatjar.jar -c ru.test.TestApps test.jar * some arguments*
```

Also, we sucessfully can run this job via api, if we register fatjar, json looks like:

```
{ 
"entryClass": "ru.test.TestApps",
"parallelism": "1",
"programArgsList" : [ *** cut *** ]
}
```

How to pass classpath (argument -C) via api?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent to the general classpath option of the CLI. The REST API always expects you to use a fat jar. Since your example also uses a fat jar, I'd point out the general flow:

1. Upload your fat jar with [/jars/upload](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/rest_api.html#jars-upload). The response contains filename (=jarid).
2. Post to [/jars/:jarid/run](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/rest_api.html#jars-jarid-run) to start your job. The response contains jobid, which you can use to query the status and cancel.

Comment: Pity. Because each job make own copy fatjar in blob directory, where space is very limited for me. Thank you for answer.

Comment: A small workaround is to put this common fatjar in /lib of your flink distribution.